# UWP KeyDown & KeyUp lag

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to complete an app where i will send the string via bluetooth to arduino. I have code that works perfectly in WPF using serialPort1. It sends the signal instantaneously via bluetooth using keydown and key up events. I am trying to replaciate this in UWP and i have been struggling for few days now. I managed to make it work however i have some lag when i press key down or up.  Signal is sent but there is like 1s of delay and i am having trouble understanding why.  here is sample of the code for WPF that works with no problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;

namespace RoverControl
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MJPEGStream stream;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyUp);
    }

    //Declare the comands for Rover control//
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)                                // Holding Keyboard Character "W" //
        {
            serialPort1.Write("F");                             // Passing command "Forward" thorugh letter "F" in arduino code //
        }

    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)                                 // Keyboard Character "W" //
        {
            serialPort1.Write("S");                             // Keyboard Character "S" //
        }

    }

    void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string IP = "";
        IP = textBox3.Text;
        stream = new MJPEGStream(IP);
        stream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame;
        try
        {
        stream.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid IP address.");
        }
    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stream.Stop();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string COM = "";
        COM = comboBox1.Text;
        serialPort1.PortName = COM;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Please select correct Comunication Port.");
        }
    }

    private void Disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Close();
    }   
}
```

}

And here is the code i have in UWP  so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;



// The Blank Page item template is documented at 
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Robot2
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection;
    private DeviceInformation selectedDevice;
    private RfcommDeviceService deviceService;

    //public string deviceName = ""; // Specify the device name to be selected; You can find the device name from the webb under bluetooth 

    StreamSocket streamSocket = new StreamSocket();


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitializeRfcommServer();
    }

    private void selectorComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
        //var BTDevinfo = DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
        // var BTDevinfo = DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort), new string[] { "System.Devices.AepService.AepId" });
        //selectorComboBox.ItemsSource = deviceCollection;

    }

    private void Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectToDevice();
    }

    private async void InitializeRfcommServer()
    {
        try
        {
            string device1 = RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort);
            deviceCollection = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(device1);
            selectorComboBox.ItemsSource = deviceCollection;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            errorStatus.Text = exception.Message;
        }
    }

    private async void ConnectToDevice()
    {
        foreach (var item in deviceCollection)
        {
            {
                selectedDevice = item;
            }
        }

        if (selectedDevice == null)
        {
            errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            errorStatus.Text = "Cannot find the device specified; Please check the device name";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            deviceService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(selectedDevice.Id);

            if (deviceService != null)
            {
                //connect the socket   
                try
                {
                    await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(deviceService.ConnectionHostName, deviceService.ConnectionServiceName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    errorStatus.Text = "Cannot connect bluetooth device:" + ex.Message;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                errorStatus.Text = "Didn't find the specified bluetooth device";
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (deviceService != null)
        {
            //send data
            string sendData = "F";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sendData))
            {
                errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                errorStatus.Text = "Please specify the string you are going to send";
            }
            else
            {
                DataWriter dwriter = new DataWriter(streamSocket.OutputStream);
                UInt32 len = dwriter.MeasureString(sendData);
                dwriter.WriteUInt32(len);
                dwriter.WriteString(sendData);
                //await dwriter.StoreAsync();
                //await dwriter.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }


    private async void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //handling code here
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.F)

        {
            string sendData = "F";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sendData))
            {
                errorStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                errorStatus.Text = "Please specify the string you are going to send";
            }
            else
            {
                DataWriter dwriter = new DataWriter(streamSocket.OutputStream);
                UInt32 len = dwriter.MeasureString(sendData);
                dwriter.WriteUInt32(len);
                dwriter.WriteString(sendData);
                await dwriter.StoreAsync();
                await dwriter.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

I have been reading about page load event that might be solution and however what i have tried didn't work. Any idea how do modify the UWP coded to avoid the lag/delay ?

Comment: Could I know how you estimate "there is like 1s of delay "?

Comment: It's an approximation. When I press key it takes about 1s for robot to move forward. When I release the key the robot is still moving forward for about 1s. But with the first code I mentioned it Is instantaneous, no delay.

Comment: Could you please try to calculate the methods executing time in UWP app and WPF separably  for comparing?

Comment: Sunteen - I am very at my beginning of C# learning and i am not sure i can set up stopwatch correctly. I have to get more knowledgeable to do so.